# Transforming data cells into rows for long format in R dataframe

Tags: r

I want to reshape my raw data and I have used a workaround for this for time but ran into problems with a more complex data set now.

My data looks like this

```
id    gender    rt
1     2         23, 50, 45, 60, 10
2     1         12, 4, 6
```

I want to transform this to a long format but ran into trouble as in this case I have cell (`rt`) that I want to make long for each `id`.

Here's how I want it to look like:

```
id    gender    rt
1     2         23
1     2         50
1     2         45
1     2         60
1     2         10
2     1         12
2     1         4
2     1         6
```

(Here the novel complexity over other data I had is that the length of `rt` differs per `id`).

I tried using `reshape` and `ldply` but couldn't get this to do what I wanted as my to-be-long data is a cell `rt` with many observations rather than many columns with single observations.

How can I transform my data to the required format?

Comment: You don't need external library or anything. Use what I have given.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can do this easily with `cSplit`

```
library(splitstackshape)
cSplit(df1, 'rt', ', ', 'long')
```

Answer (score 1):

```
l<-strsplit(mydf$rt, split = ",")
data.frame(id = rep(mydf$id, sapply(l, length)),gender= rep(mydf$gender, sapply(l, length)), rt = unlist(l))
```